# Form to search google not triggering in Angular2

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, google-search

I am trying to implement a simple search box in my app to search google (as if you were in google.com)
However, nothing seems to happen once I click the submit button. 
Is Angular2 preventing the form to trigger?

```
  <form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="31" value="">
    <button type="submit" name="button">go</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: If you use the developer tools in your browser, are there any messages in the console?

Comment: @DeborahK Thanks for your reply. No, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: I just pasted your code into an application I have and it worked as expected. It brought up the google search for the text I had entered.

Comment: Where are you located? Can you get to google.com normally?

Comment: @DeborahK Yes I did this too! That is why I find it weird it is not working within Angular2. I can get to google.com normally. No restrictions.

Comment: I added it to my Angular v2 app and it worked fine. I just pasted your form into one of my pages. I ran the app, typed in something, and the google search page appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have imported the `FormsModule` into your module.

please use `ngNoForm` on your form:`<form ngNoForm>` OR remove `FormsModule` if you dont use it.

Angular forms are activated by default on all forms except those marked with `ngNoForm` attribute. Read more here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

**where does `ngNoForm` come from?**

take a look at the doc for `NgForm`: https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html. The selector section: `form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup])` notice the `not([ngNoForm])`

Comment: I did not import the FormsModule into the component.

Comment: not your component, your **"module"** that declares that component

Answer (score 0):

@DeboraK

This is my workaround: 
I was only hoping for it to be an easier way. I am calling this function once the user presses submit.

```
  googleSearch() {
   let str = this.googlestring.searchvalue;
   let queryStr = str.split(' ').join('+');

   let googleStr = 'https://www.google.com/webhp#q=';

   let completeQueryStr = googleStr.concat(queryStr);

   console.log(this.googlestring.searchvalue);
   window.location.href = completeQueryStr;
  }
```